# Codeigniter form validation callback in model callback not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Im pretty new to this framework. The issue is that form validation callbacks are not being called inside a model. It will work inside a controller without an issue.

Am I right thinking logic/database stuff is to be inside a model rather than controller? What am I doing wrong? Im trying to do this as best as possible.

Example Model Method:

```
//The Callback
function check_delete() 
{

 $this->form_validation->set_message('check_address', 'This is a test message');
 return false;

}

function test() 
{

    //The Check
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_id', 'ID', 'required|callback_check_delete');

    //On Success
    if($this->form_validation->Run() == TRUE) {
     //Do something interesting on success!
    }

}
```

Comment: just follow this and you'll be set: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Thank you, does it not seem messy to place the logic inside a controller? :)

Comment: model: database logic, controller (incl. use of helpers, libraries): all other logic: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html#model-view-controller